# Which I'm in iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Anymore I can't create new question. Just I can change my other questions. Stackoverflow always blocking me. This is a great injustice. Anyway, I'il ask my question anyway.

The element I clicked in what iframe? I want to learn this. I want to do this with javascript or jquery. Can you show me an example? Thanks.

Comment: By design, you cannot get the path from a browser.

Comment: @ErdemCantürk I have tried to look around myself and it just doesn't seem possible.

Comment: You can find custom folder browsers for javascript but they require a server-side component. And even then you have other concerns like access level of the user vs the identity running the server process.

Comment: No, you can't. Not even with a javascript/server-side solution. I'm building a desktop app at work instead of a web app for this one stupid reason. You are already in a winforms project, can't you re-design it to get the path outside of the browser component?

Comment: I can't hear you if you don't address me, @ErdemCantürk. I am interested how that works for you but it will not solve the issue I'm having with my project so I don't intend to look into it. Since it is not a technical limitation, but a design choice, it is possible that some esoteric browser does not conform to this security measure. I do not have high hopes but I encourage you to try, keeping in mind that browser vendors spend a lot of time on security and this thing you found has me skeptical.